# How to combine four lists into a list of lists in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's say I have 4 fixed lists, all the same length:

```
val list1: List[String] = List("a", "1", "w")
val list2: List[String] = List("b", "2", "x")
val list3: List[String] = List("c", "3", "y")
val list4: List[String] = List("d", "4", "z")
```

I want to have them in a combined/composite list that returns:
`List(List("a","b","c","d"), List("1","2","3","4"), List("w","x","y","z"))`

I have tried using `fold` and `flatMap`s but I can't seem to understand fully how to implement this. If someone can also explain a good solution as well so that I can learn, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is the number of lists fixed? Are you sure that they will have the same size?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not elaborating more. There are 4 fixed lists and each of their length is the same. They are each a column in a text file.

Comment: Your list types are wrong FYI, that code won't compile

Comment: @Celeski you just want to `zip` them all, and them manipulate the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transpose`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.2/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#transpose[B](implicitasIterable:A=%3EIterable[B]):CC[CC[B]@scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance]):

```
val list1 = List("a", "1", "w")
val list2 = List("b", "2", "x")
val list3 = List("c", "3", "y")
val list4 = List("d", "4", "z")

List(list1, list2, list3, list4).transpose
// List(List(a, b, c, d), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(w, x, y, z))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Updated answer, after reading updated question carefully** :)

```
val list1: List[String] = List("a", "1", "w")
val list2: List[String] = List("b", "2", "x")
val list3: List[String] = List("c", "3", "y")
val list4: List[String] = List("d", "4", "z")

val result = List(list1, list2, list3, list4)
        .flatMap(_.zipWithIndex)
        .groupBy{ case(value,index) => index}
        .values
        .toList
        .map(_.map(_._1))
```

Also in your code, those should be `List[String]`

Comment: I thought the same thing because the title is misleading, read the question carefully and check what the OP wants to return. They want to zip

Comment: This also solves my question. Just added reverse at the end to keep the order the same and it works great! Thanks for taking the time to help out!

Comment: Helped we out too - was not aware of transpose method